# SQL query with ranking order

Tags: db2

All,
   Need a help with one of the sql queries. I have a query which pulls up records on ranking order.

```
Select * from 
(select count(*) cnt, customer_cd, smallint(Rank() Over(Order by count(8) Desc)) as rnk
from table.customer
```

Now, the result shows like,

```
Cnt   Customer Cd
110   1- Retail
90    2-Human resources
20    3-Information Technology
11    Not Standard
```

I want to remove the description from it and will have only the Customer Codes such as 1,2,3,NS etc. Any help how to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the field 'customer_cd" in the table "customer" have that description? If yes, you might be able to selected everything before the hyphen. If not, where is the description coming from?

Comment: Yes, the description is in the table.

Comment: We might have to use string and Locate function but not sure about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LOCATE to find the position of the hyphen, assuming you always have a hyphen. Then, you could use SUBSTRING to get the portion of the string before the position found by LOCATE.

```
select substring(customer_cd,0,locate('-',customer_cd)) 
from table.customer
```

should show you what you will get.

You do seem to have some data (e.g. "Non Standard") that has no code at all. Such fields will come out as blank. If you want to replace that with some specific code, you can use a CASE...END expression.

```
select CASE when locate('-',customer_cd)==0 then "" 
       else substring(customer_cd,0, locate('-',customer_cd) ) END
from table.customer
```

Comment: Used it. I believe it would be SUBSTR, and the error it is showing is,A numeric argument of a built-in string function is out of range.

Comment: My version of DB2 supports both SUBSTR() and SUBSTRING(). You probably need a case expression so that you do not use SUBSTR()  when the hyphen is not found. Will edit the answer above to show how.